# Icon engine with custom colors, per icon 2 colors

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, graphic

I have collection of icons, white/black, exist any possibility to edit this icons live, i mean this so if i give any two colors in back office, for example, red/blue, so are my icons not white/black, but red/blue, it is possible to do with jQuery or PHP?

Comment: If by "edit" you mean "change colors and sizes", then you could try using an icon font.

Comment: it is possible with pure css if you use font icons

Comment: yeah, just use font icons, its superb for mobile, looks sharp... print works as well..

Comment: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Comment: woooooooow, that's really better then png icons, thanks guys :), this is very, very helpfully for me

Comment: @reyaner ... you should post that or a generalization of that as a solution.